# How to show Line string feature dynamically while Zoom In /Zoom Out using OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, html, zooming, openlayers, styling

I am using roads file to display on the map using OpenLayers.currently, I manage to assign styling based on road type but when I run the server I can see all the data displayed.
[image]
Is there any way I can show only primary roads(e.g. when I run server it should only show the orange color roads first on a map and after zooming it should show other roads) when I run the server and can see further secondary roads after zoom in like the way google maps or open street map displays? I tried using minZoom in my code but it does not work. Also how I can change the thickness of stroke dynamically while zoom in/zoom out?

code

```
var styleRoadFunction = function(feature) {
       console.log(feature);
     //assign symbology of roads based on road type
      var color;
      var outerColor;
      var lightStroke;
      var darkStroke;
      //var maxZoom;
      var minZoom;
      if (feature.get("type")=='primary' && 'secondary' && 'trunk'){
      color = 'rgba(252, 214, 112, 1)',
      outerColor ='rgba(252, 214, 112, 1)',
      lightStroke = 'null',
      darkStroke = 'null';
      //minZoom = 13.999;
       } else if (feature.get("type")=='motorway'){
      color = 'rgba(245, 171, 53, 1)',
      outerColor ='rgba(245, 171, 53, 1)',
      lightStroke = 'null',
      darkStroke = 'null';
      //minZoom = 12.999;
      }else if (feature.get("type")=='cycleway'){
      color = 'rgba(3, 166, 120, 1)',
      outerColor = 'rgba(3, 166, 120, 1)',
      lightStroke ='rgba(236, 240, 241, 1)',
      darkStroke = 'rgba(3, 166, 120, 1)';
      } else {
      color = 'rgba(236, 236, 236, 1)',
      outerColor = 'rgba(189, 195, 199, 1)',
      lightStroke = 'null',
      darkStroke = 'null';
      //minZoom =3
      //maxZoom= 7;
      }
      

      var retStyle =   [new ol.style.Style({
        
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ 
        color: outerColor,
        lineCap: 'butt',
        lineJoin:'round',
        tolerence: 5,
        width: 7,
        //maxZoom:  maxZoom,
        //minZoom : minZoom,
        opacity: 0,
        zIndex: 0
      })
      }),
        new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ 
            color: color,
            lineCap:'butt',
            lineJoin: 'round',
            tolerence: 5,
           // maxZoom:  maxZoom,
            //minZoom: minZoom,
            opacity:0,
            width: 6,
            zIndex:1,
           })
      
        }),
        new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ 
            color: lightStroke,
            //width: 5,
            width: 2,
            lineDash: [4,8],
            lineDashOffset: 6
            //zIndex:5
          })
        }),
        new ol.style.Style({
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ 
            color: darkStroke,
            //width: 5,
            width: 5,
            lineDash: [4,8],
            //lineDashOffset: 6,
            //zIndex:1
          })
        }),
      ];
       return retStyle;

      };

    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
            source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
            format: new ol.format.MVT(),
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt'
        }),
        style:styleRoadFunction,
        
        declutter: true
     })  
   
         
    var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [osmLayer,vectorLayer],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([103.8198,1.3521]),
          zoom: 14
          })
      });
```

Comment: style functions take feature and resolution `var styleRoadFunction = function(feature, reolution) {` so you can adjust the output depending on resolution as well as feature type

Comment: the roads differented with layers .for a particulsr zoom lavel display according to your layer .follow the url https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24987/different-level-of-detaillayers-on-different-zoom-level-at-openlayers-map

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the reply . I try adding var styleRoadFunction = function(feature, resolution) and also defined a var zoom =14 and  assigning that zoom in each if-else statement with different value of zoom .but it does not change anything. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code would look something like

```
var styleRoadFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
      var zoom = map.getView().getZoomForResolution();
      var type = feature.get("type");
       console.log(feature);
     //assign symbology of roads based on road type
      var color;
      var outerColor;
      var lightStroke;
      var darkStroke;
      //var maxZoom;
      var minZoom;
      if ((type == 'primary' || type == 'secondary' || type == 'trunk') && zoom >= 13.999){
        color = 'rgba(252, 214, 112, 1)',
        outerColor ='rgba(252, 214, 112, 1)',
        lightStroke = 'null',
        darkStroke = 'null';
        //minZoom = 13.999;
      } else if (type == 'motorway' && zoom >= 12.999){
        color = 'rgba(245, 171, 53, 1)',
        outerColor ='rgba(245, 171, 53, 1)',
        lightStroke = 'null',
        darkStroke = 'null';
        //minZoom = 12.999;
      } else if (type == 'cycleway' && zoom >= ???){
        color = 'rgba(3, 166, 120, 1)',
        outerColor = 'rgba(3, 166, 120, 1)',
        lightStroke ='rgba(236, 240, 241, 1)',
        darkStroke = 'rgba(3, 166, 120, 1)';
      } else if (zoom >= ???){
        color = 'rgba(236, 236, 236, 1)',
        outerColor = 'rgba(189, 195, 199, 1)',
        lightStroke = 'null',
        darkStroke = 'null';
        //minZoom =3
        //maxZoom= 7;
      }
```

Comment: I tried using the above code but it does not work. after changing to this it provides the same result as before and loads all the road together not displaying using provided zoom level.